# Why do American supermarkets only carry lamb and not mutton?

Tags: meat, lamb, mutton

When I go to the supermarket I do not see much, if any, mutton, just a lot of lamb.

So, I have postulated some possible explanations:

1. mutton (the meat of a sheep) is being sold as "lamb",
2. mutton tastes weird to Americans so all of it is exported,
3. mutton tastes weird to Americans so it is turned into dog food,
4. all adult sheep are only used for wool and are then retired and put out to pasture where they live out their retirement years playing pinochle and shuffleboard.

What's the explanation, why is there is so little mutton and so much lamb meat?

Comment: Most lamb in the US is imported from New Zealand... we don't produce a ton of it locally... And, no, we generally don't like eating mutton. You're more likely to find it in a specialty market.

Comment: So, in New Zealand do they have mutton for breakfast, lunch and dinner?

Comment: You don't get mutton unless you let the baby sheep live... which they generally don't. I'm pretty certain they don't eat a huge amount of mutton in New Zealand, either.

Comment: What about all the wool sheep? What do the baby killers do with all those?

Comment: One of the strongest ethical objections in knitting (besides mulesing) is that the adult sheep get transported to the Middle East under appalling conditions, where the animals which did not suffocate en route are slaughtered and eaten. So, not 4.

Comment: Also, depending on the country, number 1 would be illegal.

Comment: 2/3(b) might apply: they've never tasted it, but *think* it's cheap/tough/unappetising so don't buy it.  So it's not sold, so no one tastes it...

Comment: As a side note: all sheep are not equal. Like in other domestic animals you typically have different breeds for different purposes. Some breeds are "better" for wool, others that grow quicker and are larger are breed for meat etc. (Though there are quite a few "multi-purpose breeds".)

Comment: have you been to supermarkets all across the us? if not, you might want to specify your region. there is a LOT of variance across the states. it's a big country. walking into one supermarket and looking around doesn't tell you much at all about what "american supermarkets" are like.

Comment: This is also an issue in the UK

Comment: in NZ (where I am) we only see lamb in supermarkets. Mutton might be sold in specialty stores but I would not expect the average person to want to eat mutton (or even know its existence).

Comment: In response to item 1: Mutton dressed as lamb? Are you implying they're pulling the wool over your eyes?

Comment: I wasn't aware there was a difference between lamb (the meat of sheep) and mutton (the meat of sheep). I had to look them up to find the difference.  I'd never made the connection that 'lamb' is the meat of lambs, young sheep.  Also, we don't eat much lamb errr sheep here, so I don't think there's much demand for two different types of sheep meat, and so if people want sheep they probably want the most tender of the two and not the more gamy of the two.

Comment: In Spain popular wisdom advises one not to mix "churras" with merino (two different kinds of sheep); because the result won't be good for meat, like the first, neither wool, like the second.

Comment: Although this isn't directly an answer to the question, there is some [history involved](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheep_Wars) in any discussion of why sheep are not commercially raised in the United States. In a nutshell, there were actual armed conflicts as well as acts of sabotage between ranchers of sheep and cattle during the 1800's and early 1900's across much of the western US. Although the reasons for those conflicts have largely been removed, large-scale sheep operations have never taken hold.

Comment: Americans as a group can be fairly homogenous in our tastes. Any store trying to cater to the most consumers in the USA will have to have beef, pork, chicken, and turkey products, but anything outside the big four is not widely popular. Smaller stores and boutiques carry all kinds of meats, but the larger supermarkets actually tend to cater to a more narrow audience, not a broader one.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

It's not just American supermarkets that rarely carry mutton, this situation is similar across the Anglosphere, and I suspect most Western countries too (or at least those without a strong mutton culture). The reason is largely economic. **Mutton is expensive and not as tasty as lamb.**

- First, the immediate reason is that **nobody really eats mutton anymore.** Yes, there are certain locales, cultures and movements still eating mutton or are trying to bring it back, but today, on aggregate, the demand for mutton is near zero. According to the [USDA](http://www.ers.usda.gov/topics/animal-products/sheep,-lamb-mutton/background.aspx):

  > The U.S. market for lamb and mutton has weakened throughout the decades. Since the 1960s, per capita consumption has dropped from nearly 5 pounds to just about 1 pound. This drop is due in part to declining acceptance of lamb from a growing segment of the population, as well as competition from other meats, such as poultry, pork, and beef. Most meat is sold as lamb and comes from animals under 14 months old.

  Here's a per-capita consumption graph:

  [image: per capita consumption]

  If nobody buys mutton, supermarkets don't sell them. The supply chain for meats is pretty complex; it's not something that a store manager can just decide one day to order a batch and shelve to see if it sells. Meat needs to be slaughtered and deboned in an abattoir, butchered either in store butcheries or at centres (unless you fancy buying an entire, 50kg cut), and displayed in refrigerated sections. If there's enough local demand for mutton then maybe individual supermarkets can carry them, just as meats like rabbit, duck or kangaroo is sometimes sold at a few supermarkets.
- But why don't people eat mutton? **People just don't like it. It is an [inferior good](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inferior_good).**

  > Mutton comes from older animals and is often less expensive but less desirable to consumers. (USDA)

  .

  > As can be seen, the average income elasticities across the studies are 0.77 for
  >   beef, 0.24 for lamb, -0.65 for mutton, 0.47 for chicken and 0.48 for pork.

  (Negative income inelasticity = inferior good) That is, as incomes grow, as they have over this timeframe, people want to buy less of it.
- **Lamb is a superior substitute for mutton.** Anecdotally, compared to lamb, mutton is gamier, tougher, and harder to cook. Economically, lamb and mutton have high cross-price elasticity - if one's price grows, demand shifts to the other, indicating that they are substitutes. And the real killer is...
- **Mutton prices have grown faster than lamb.**

  [image: meat prices]

  Mutton is still cheaper than lamb, but in relative terms it has become more economic to raise and sell lamb. There are multiple market forces at play: the cost of raising the sheep past lamb age, the efficiency of raising lambs (i.e. increased lamb weight), the growth of dairy leading to higher beef supply, the relative decline in wool reducing mutton supply and so on. You'll have to ask a farmer.

[*Source: Changing Pattern of Meat Consumption in Australia by Lucille Wong, E A Selvanathan and Saroja Selvanathan*](http://www.murdoch.edu.au/School-of-Management-and-Governance/_document/Australian-Conference-of-Economists/Changing-pattern-of-meat-consumption-in-Australia.pdf)

*Update: didn't notice that the graph was price indices and not actual prices*

Comment: What's the mid-1970s Beef Boom about??

Comment: @AakashM It was more of an unsustainable growth thing - postwar boom and improving agriculture efficiency lowered the cost and increased availability.  Oil shocks, economic turmoil, and the dawn of healthier eating consciousness (ie: bad press) turned the tide.  The 70s were one big bubble in a lot of ways - socially, economically... the west, and the US especially, had its first postmodern existential crisis, the fallout of which we're still pretty much dealing with today.

Comment: @congusbongus price indices works well to show how prices have increased relative to inflation. It seems that each price starts as the baseline 100 so you can also see the relative change between different kinds of meat. But it won't give an idea of their actual current price.

Comment: Not sure id agree with lamb is tastier than mutton, mutton will have a stronger flavour, although lamb should be more tender

Comment: Is there a reason you keep talking about the US but all of your graphs and data is from Australia?

Answer (score 21):

As has been mentioned, most of the lamb in the US is imported -- and [mutton is imported, too](http://modernfarmer.com/2013/12/mutton/)

There's a giant consumer of mutton in western Kentucky around Owensboro.  (it's the local standard for barbecue, and past reports put Owensboro near the top of the list for both for per capita number of and spending at restaurants)

As we now have a lot of smaller sheep farms making cheese and wool, especially in mountainous regions, I would suspect that there are people eating mutton, but it may be that they're keeping it for themselves.  There's also a possibility of selling it to ethnic butchers, as sheep and goat are popular in some european, asian and middle eastern cuisines.  (I know I can get rabbit at one of the local Italian markets, and goat at a local asian market)

Although I suspect that there may be some labeling issues in selling mutton as 'lamb' (much like people would be upset if you sold beef as veal), I've heard that some butchers who make Merguez sausage will use a blend of mutton and lamb -- the spices mask the possible gaminess of the mutton, but there's still lamb in it so they can label it as such.

I'd suggest looking in your area to see if there are large farmer's markets -- there are often farmers selling meat, cheese, and yarn there.  If you find someone selling sheep products, you can ask them about obtaining mutton or hogget (1 to 2 year old sheep).

Comment: +1, I had no idea there was a mutton-based regional barbecue style.

Comment: @DanC : it helps that I lived in KY, and did some contract work which required visiting a lot of out-of-the-way places  (where the large jails were).  The others who were on that trip insisted that we had to go to Moonlite.  That was 15+ years ago, so I don't think I could accurately describe it from memory, but I remember enjoying it.

Comment: If you go to a grocery store, you see a lot of beef and very little veal. The terms 'mutton' and 'lamb' map to the terms 'beef' and 'veal' for sheep and cows, respectively. This question is asking why, when you go to a grocery store at see a lot of adult cow meat and very little child cow meat, yet for sheep the situation is reversed, you see a lot of child sheep meat and very little adult sheep meat. The fact that mutton is imported, that it is used a lot in kentucky, and that you might be able to get mutton from a local farm don't even attempt to answer the question. 1/2

Comment: 2/2 The idea that the vast majority of adult sheep meat gets sold only in ethnic shops is very hard to believe without any sort of data. I think you are on track with the labeling issue. But that only makes up a tiny part of your answer.

Comment: I think summarizing that link as "mutton is imported" is doing it and your answer a disservice: it does also talk about Americans not liking the taste as much, and mentions that a lot of mutton is used as dog/cat food, sometimes even baby food, and sausage, which is a pretty direct answer to the OP's question.

Comment: "There's a giant consumer of mutton in western Kentucky around Owensboro"  Hey, enough with the fat shaming!

Answer (score 5):

Here in New Mexico, the Navajo raise sheep, and eat a lot of mutton.  It is definitely an acquired taste; pretty "gamey" to me.  Nearly all the lamb sold in stores here is from New Zealand or Australia. It is not possible to find mutton in regular stores here. I have never seen mutton sold as lamb; I don't think it would sell, except near a reservation, and there would be issues about false labelling. You can definitely tell the difference - even by sight - between mutton and lamb.  I have also lived on the East Coast and the West Coast (but over a decade ago) and I have never seen mutton for sale in stores.

Answer (score 0):

Barbecued mutton is common in western Kentucky, such as in the area around Paducah. I do not know if this is still popular since I have not been there in many years. I did find at least one supplier by an on line search: Hampton Premium Meats in Hopkinsville, KY.

As others have noted mutton has a very strong flavor and most Americans would not care for it.

Answer (score -2):

The answer is #1.

There is no term for Hogget or Mutton in North America. All meat from a sheep is called 'lamb' regardless of its age. So likely, all lamb sold in the US would be called mutton elsewhere. (It is possible that it is all actually young sheep, or some is young some is old -- but I doubt it.)

**Relevant regulation:**

> Under current federal regulations (2014 CFR §65.190), only the term
> 'lamb' is used:
>
> Lamb — ovine animals of any age, including ewes and rams
>
> The terms
> 'mutton' and 'hogget' are rare in the United States. Nevertheless, the
> exclusive use of 'lamb' in the United States may be confusing,
> particularly if it is assumed that only actual lambs are butchered for
> their meat. Under the previous definition (2010 CFR §65.190), 'lamb'
> meant 'meat, other than mutton (or yearling mutton), produced from
> sheep'.

Comment: Shane, after a discussion in [chat] I removed my basically identical answer because the Wikipedia article (links please next time!) is a bit questionable - the CFR is far more vague than Wikipedia states.

Comment: Yeah, I'm pretty certain that this isn't a good interpretation of this regulation. The [text of it](https://www.gpo.gov/fdsys/pkg/CFR-2011-title7-vol3/pdf/CFR-2011-title7-vol3-sec65-165.pdf) is, literally, and in its entirety "Lamb means meat produced from sheep." It doesn't ever say "all sheep". Similar definitions include "Beef means meat produced from cattle, including Veal." It's literally just a glossary in the text. Additionally, there certainly **are** stores in the US that sell "mutton"... It's just not sold in the average grocery.

Comment: Wikipedia is unfortunately wrong here. The referenced 7 CFR §65.190 is being used out of context. It's part of a list of definitions that only apply to 7 CFR Part 65 - COUNTRY OF ORIGIN LABELING OF BEEF, PORK, LAMB, CHICKEN, GOAT MEAT, PERISHABLE AGRICULTURAL COMMODITIES, MACADAMIA NUTS, PECANS, PEANUTS, AND GINSENG. This definition of "lamb" is only used in the definition of "ground lamb" which in turn is only used in 7 CFR 65.300 (h) which sets rules for determining the countries of origin of ground meat.  It doesn't place any requirements how lamb and mutton is identified on labels.

Comment: @Catija I'm not sure what part you are taking issue with. Legally, 'Lamb means meat produced from sheep.' This is why you don't see any mutton, it is what the law says, it is what my answers says. Is my answer not clear? Is  my interpretation wrong? Sure there are stores that call it mutton. As long as you don't call it something it is not, you can call it whatever you want. You can take a slab of cow meat and call it "meat of the gods". As long as the law doesn't specify MotG as something else, there's no problem. If you took a slab of beef and called it 'chicken' then you'd have a problem.

Comment: You can't take Wikipedia articles as gold. They aren't always correct. See Ross's comment for verification. Your answer is simply wrong. You can **definitely** buy mutton at specialty stores that cater to people who regularly eat mutton... for example, Middle Eastern and Indian groceries... Lamb is almost always exactly that... "baby sheep". The two taste very different.

Comment: @RossRidge If you say so! You seem to have a lot of knowledge about this.If wikipedia is wrong, you should ***definitely*** go and edit it so that it is accurate. Also, post a correct answer here. As it stands now I'm not sure anything you've said changes or invalidates the gist of my answer: the reason you don't see things labeled as 'mutton' in the US is because that isn't a term used in the US. Even in legalese - which is always more precise and elaborate than colloquialisms - 'mutton' isn't a thing.

Comment: @Catija Of course you can go to a specialty store and get things labeled with fancy labels. That doesn't mean anything in my answer is wrong. Sorry. Everything you are saying in this comment is in my answer! "It is possible that it is all actually young sheep, or some is young some is old -- but I doubt it." Did you miss that part? The part that says the same thing you are complaining I didn't say at all?

Comment: @Shane I think y'all are talking past each other a bit here. First off, "mutton" *is* a term in North America. The fact that most people don't eat it doesn't mean that there is no term. And second, mutton tastes quite different from lamb. Given that people who specifically want mutton end up going to specialty stores, I think we can infer that the lamb sold in most stores is *not* mutton, so your claim that "all lamb sold in the US would be called mutton elsewhere" is likely also not correct. It probably *is* all young sheep. (If it weren't, people would notice very inconsistent taste.)

Comment: It's true that there is *some potential* for ambiguity with these terms, and I think that's valuable to acknowledge—for example, I've seen "mutton" used to refer to goat in some contexts—but I afraid this answer is too absolute and would be a bit misleading. I spend a lot of time deciphering sections of the CFR (albeit usually not ag/livestock regs) and situations like this are common, definitions apply to very limited sections and sometimes differ between sections, purely for the purpose of writing regs that *read more simply*.

Answer (score -7):

Mutton is the meat from GOAT and lamb is the meat from sheep. Lamb or sheep meat tends to be softer and easier to cook than mutton, which usually requires a pressure cooker to cook properly. Mutton is chewy meat and not so soft as lamb. Mutton is popular in India and the UK ( adopted from India) and usually served as curries. New zealand and Australia produce most of the lamb in the world but mutton is available almost everywhere. Just need to look for Goat meat!

Comment: [This may be the case where you live](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goat_meat), but in the US, this is not true. "Goat" is the meat from goats or "kid" (for young goats) or "chevon" (for adult goats). "Mutton" is meat from adult sheep.

Comment: Not the case in Australia, UK, or New Zealand either.

Comment: Or South Africa

Comment: Is there any English-speaking case where this is at all true? I know that there are places where *mutton* covers both sheep and goat, but is there anywhere where it is generally understood as only goat?

Comment: Anecdotally, in the American rural South I've bought goat meat that was labeled "Mutton" in the official packaging. Pretty sure it was actually goat as thats what I asked for, and it tasted like other goat dishes I'd made.

Comment: [This question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/167738/why-is-mutton-used-for-both-sheep-meat-and-goat-meat) might be relevant for terminology. As one answer mentions, part of the confusion is likely because many places simply don't eat much of either meat (I've eaten goat meat a few times, but can't remember ever eating sheep). I've never heard of *chevon* or *cabrito*, and couldn't remember what *mutton* was when I read the title to this question. I thought maybe it was goat meat since I know sheep is called *lamb* and didn't know what goat was called.

Comment: Curried Goat is a Caribbean staple, and commonly eaten by migrant families in the UK (and is delicious) - however, as goat meat isn't that common in the UK, it is often substituted for Mutton...

Comment: @JonHanna yes, in Asia mutton generally means goat, not sheep. This confused me when I first visited Singapore, which is an English-speaking country.